# How can I fix the error: "format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’"

Tags: c, arguments, printf

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int year;

    printf("enter year:");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    if (year % 4 == 0) {
        printf("%d is a leap year :", &year);
    }
    else if (year % 100 == 0) {
        printf("%d is a leap year :", &year);
    }
    else if (year % 400 == 0) {
        printf("%d is a leap year :", &year);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d is not a leap year", &year);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I getting this error:

```
format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

Comment: Remove the & from the printf &year argument.

Comment: The unary `&` operator gets you the address of a variable. You usually need the address of variables if you want to modify them in a function. That's why `scanf()` requires it. But `printf()` only reads from it and does not need to modify it.

Comment: The tests you are using to determine whether or not a year is a leap year will not produce the correct result.

Comment: @Shivbardhan Kumar: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and upvote those that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

The intent of your code seems to be:

1. Have an `int` allocated in memory. It's name is `year`. It resides at an address known as `&year` which is a `int *`, or a *pointer-to-int*.
2. The `scanf` will determine the value for year. You pass the *address* of `year` so that `scanf` knows where you want the value stored.
3. Now, having done so, the *value* is at `year` which is an `int`. But you are calling `printf("%d is a leap year :",&year)` with `&year` which is a *pointer to int* or `int *`.

And this is exactly what the message states. I hope this will help you interpret these kinds of messages in the future, because they never really stop....

Answer (score 2):

There is a significant difference between `scanf` and `printf` functions:

- `scanf` requires a pointer to the object (it is why you need to use `&` when you want to `scanf` an `int` and place it in the variable having `int` type) as it **modifies** the object referenced by the pointer passed to the `scanf` function
- `printf` wants to know only the **value** of the parameter as it does not modify it. So you do not use the reference (address) `&` operator

Answer (score 1):

`printf` expects an argument of type `int` for the `%d` format, but you are passing `&year`, which is the *address* of `year`, ie: a pointer to `int`, instead of passing the *value* of `year`.  Use this instead:

```
    printf("%d is a leap year\n", year);
```

The reason for this error is the confusion with `scanf` which expects a pointer to `int` for the `%d` conversion in order to *store* the value read and converted.

Note also these remarks:

- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid or missing input.
- the logic to check for leap years is incorrect: a *leap* year in the Gregorian calendar is divisible by 4, but not by 100 unless it is also divisible by 400.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int year;

    printf("enter year: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &year) != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)) {
            printf("%d is a leap year\n", year);
        } else {
            printf("%d is not a leap year\n", year);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```